# Mapping & Unmapping an operator

Tags: vim

I want to define my own key-bindings in vim (overriding the default ones):

1) how to map an operator ? for example I want to map the delete operator to "l" key, so ll will delete the whole line and lw the current word.

2) How to unmap an operator? i want to unmap the delete operator from the d key, so I can use this key (d) for another thing, I tried to simply remapping the "d" key to another action(eg nmap d k) but this causes a delay of one second when pressing "d" (because vim is waiting for the motion).

a main reason for doing this is my keyboard has a numeric-keypad , i don't want to switch my right hand from the hjkl to the numbers-pad every time i type a number(which happens a lot), i prefer to change hjkl to asdf, fixing my left hand on movements  and special keys(crtl, shift ,esc)  and using my right hand for others commands . my productivity improve considerably that way.

Comment: That's a *very* bad idea for so many reasons. Why don't you take the time to learn Vim instead?

Comment: i'm familiar with vim, but the current key-bindings aren't very effective especially if you have a numeric key-pad , for example in normal mode you have to switch your right hand from the hjkl to the numeric keypad every time you manipulate  numbers, i' trying to use the qsdf instead .
also, a bad idea doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: You can unmap keymappings using `unmap d` for example, which would unmap `d`, however I'm not sure how you would unmap all of it's child keymappings (as I call them).

Comment: @Eduan It won’t ever unmap d because `d` is a *normal-mode command*, not a mapping. I.e. built-in thing that cannot be ever changed without editing source code (or vim binary if you have nothing at all to do). All you can do is mask it with some mapping.

Comment: @ZyX Ah, disregard my comment Pindexis, I just learnt something new.

Comment: What about buying a normal keyboard? =)

Comment: @romainl, it does not look like a bad idea to me. I have remapped almost all my Vim keybindings, trying to chose mappings based on key positions and not on characters, and mapping to more useful functions. I am still experimenting with my setup, but I feel free as a bird.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t unmap d to free it for some other thing. You don’t even need to: doing

```
nnoremap l d
```

will map `l` to do the same thing as `d` (note: this won’t allow `ll`).

```
nnoremap d {some-other-thing}
```

will map `d` to do some other thing, you don’t need to free something here. More, after doing all of the above

```
nnoremap l c
```

will make `l` have the same meaning as `c` without any unmapping: `*map` commands override existing mappings unless they are given `<unique>` argument.

---

To allow `ll` you have some options:

```
nnoremap ll dd
```

or

```
onoremap l d
```

. Note that I unfortunately don’t know a motion that means same thing as repeated character, but is not operator-dependant. Thus `ll` will work in the last case, but `cl` will fail just as `cd` does.

---

The fact that it is possible does not make it a good idea if you constantly work on another’s machines though. Neither it makes it a bad idea if you know you don’t. If everybody cared about using another’s machines you would be using notepad, without `++`.